# Javascript generate 100 steps in between two range values

Tags: javascript, html, angular, range

I need to actually generate steps of 100 in between two values, I tried several ways but couldn't succeed.  
The minimum value is **-0.1** and the maximum is **0.1**. I actually need somehow to calculate the 100 steps starting from -0.1 till 0.1. I have an input range in this code:

```js
$('#slider').change(function(){
    var val = ($(this).val());
    console.log(val);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input  type="range" min="-0.1" max='0.1' value="-0.1" step="0.1" id="slider" >
```

As you can see it outputs the correct values i.e minimum -0.1 and maximum 0.1. but the problem is the steps. Somehow i want to make this slider smooth but increasing the steps. Currently its jumping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems you need to change the step attribute. The min value is -0.1 and max value s +0.1. So range is 0.2. So probably steps will be 0.2/100

```js
$('#slider').change(function() {
  var val = ($(this).val());
  console.log(val);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="range" min="-0.1" max='0.1' value="-0.1" step="0.002" id="slider">
```

Comment: it works fine with normal html. But it seems that problem is with angular. When i bind negative value with angular model, the range values doesnt accept it. `<input type="range" min="-0.1" max='0.1' value="-0.1" step="0.002" id="slider" [(ngModel)]="currentValue" 
                                                            [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">` while `currentValue = -0.1`